# How to call a Rust function from a Python file using pyo3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rust, pyo3

I'm working on a videogame in which I'll need to set Rust objects (like, add a button with `texture:"", coords:"", text:"", action:""`) from Python files.

I'm using the pyo3 crate to link Python and Rust. I succeed calling Python scripts from my Rust code, but I can't find how to call a Rust function from a Python file.

Rust code that executes my Python script:

```rust
fn main() -> PyResult<()> {
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py = gil.python();
    let script = fs::read_to_string("deep_hello.py")?;

    println!("RUNNING :\n[\n{}]", script);
    py.run(&script, None, None)
}
```

Rust function that I'd like to call from my Python script:

```rust
/// hello_from_rust(/)
/// --
///
/// This function prints hello because she is very nice.
#[pyfunction]
fn hello_from_rust() {
    println!("Hello from rust from python !");
}
```

My Python script:

```py
hello_from_rust()
```

I'm getting this output:

```
RUNNING :
[
hello_from_rust()
]
Error: PyErr { type: Py(0x7f9cdd1e9580, PhantomData) }
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your issue correctly, what you're trying to do involves three steps:

1. Create a Python module containing the function `hello_from_rust()`
2. Use it in a Python script `deep_hello.py`
3. Run `deep_hello.py` from within Rust.

I wasn't able to completely reproduce your issue, but it seems like the root of your problem might be in the first or second step.

## Defining a Python module using PyO3

From the [PyO3 documentation](https://pyo3.rs/v0.10.1/), I would expect `hello_from_rust()` to be in a Rust file defining a Python module that looks something like this:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::wrap_pyfunction;

#[pyfunction]
fn hello_from_rust() {
    println!("Hello from rust from python !");
}

#[pymodule]
fn hello_module(py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_wrapped(wrap_pyfunction!(hello_from_rust));

    Ok(())
}
```

You can build this into a Python module with Cargo (see [here](https://pyo3.rs/v0.10.1/#using-rust-from-python); instructions are slightly different depending on your OS) and place the resulting `.so` (Linux or MacOS) or `.pyd` (Windows) file in the same directory as your Python script.

### Note

You have to create a function something along the lines of `hello_module` to initialize your Python module. If you don't, your Rust library might still compile, but you won't be able to import `hello_from_rust`.

## Using your new Python module

Your `deep_hello.py` script should look like this:

```py
import hello_module
hello_module.hello_from_rust()
```

Making sure that the `.so` or `.pyd` file is accessible in your `PYTHON_PATH` (eg by putting it in the same directory as your script), running `deep_hello.py` with Python >= 3.5 should work. (Note that your system Python is probably Python 2, so you might want to create an Anaconda environment with a newer version of Python and work from in there.)

For me, following these steps did the trick.

```sh
(ruspy) ruspy $ python deep_hello.py
Hello from rust from python !
```

### Note

Make sure you remember to `import hello_module` in your Python script! The `PyErr` returned by your `py.run(&script, None, None)` makes me wonder if the problem is actually in your Python script, and indeed I would expect `hello_from_rust()` without a preceding `from deep_hello import *` to produce a `NameError`, even if you put together your `deep_hello` module correctly.

## Calling Rust from Python from Rust

I'm not totally sure why you want to do this, but you should now be able to run `deep_hello.py` from Rust.